# staticserver.port not having any effect in Adobe Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets

I'm trying to set a static port for the Live Preview feature in Adobe Brackets (Release 1.7 build 1.7.0-16898 release b0a363b71). I've read that this is accomplished via the staticserver.port setting in the brackets.json file. I've added this setting to the brackets.json file, and have restarted brackets, but it does not end up forcing the port to the value I have specified. Live Preview still assigns a random port even though I have specified port 49993.

This is the contents of my brackets.json file:

```
{
    "staticserver.port": 49993,
    "insertHintOnTab": false,
    "fonts.fontSize": "17px",
    "fonts.fontFamily": "'SourceCodePro-Medium', ＭＳ ゴシック, 'MS Gothic', monospace",
    "livedev.multibrowser": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to uncheck "Enable Theseus" in the File menu. Doing this allows the staticserver.port setting to be used.